# Is there a transaction queue for single wallet in Ethereum?

Tags: transactions, ethereum

I have executed contract method with very low gas price - 1 gwei (transaction **A**).

After that I sent some eth to several wallets from the same account (transaction **B**).

As the result, the state of transaction **A** was `pending` for about 12 hours until it was mined because of the gas price. And I found that the transactions **B** stalled until the transaction **A** was mined (they were also `pending`).

All transactions were sent from the same wallet through MyEthereWallet.

As I understand, transactions are executed absolutely independently. Then, why transactions **B** where mined only after **A**? Or there is a global transaction queue for each wallet and transactions are mined in the order they go to the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer [here](https://medium.com/@preethikasireddy/how-does-ethereum-work-anyway-22d1df506369). If shortly, yes, there is a kind of queue. Transactions are executed in the order they are published to ethereum network.

---

A little bit more detail. Each account has a property called `nonce`. It contains the number of transactions sent out of the account.

Next. Each transaction sent by account has several properties. One of them is `nonce` of account which sent the transaction.

Before execution transactions are checked for validity - they should have valid signature, enough gas and valid `nonce` - it should be equal to the current `nonce` of sender's account.

After check for validity the transaction is being executed. After successful transaction execution account's nonce is incremented.

For example, our account's `nonce` is 100. We publish two transactions with `nonce` 100 and 101. The second transaction with `nonce` 101 is not valid until the first transaction is finished and account's `nonce` is incremented (and become 101).